# Basic doubt related to property of Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f\in L^1$ such that $\hat{f}\in L^1.$

1. $\hat{f}\in L^1\implies f$ is continuous.
2. Define $g(x)=\begin{cases} 0 , \text{ if } x\in \mathbb{Q}\\ f(x), \text{ if } 
   x\in \mathbb{Q}^c  \end{cases} . $ Then $f=g$ a.e.
3. So  $g\in L^1$ and $\hat{f}=\hat{g}$.
4. So $\hat{g}\in L^1$ and hence $g$ is continuous.
5. So $g\equiv 0$ and hence $f\equiv 0$.

Please help me find the flaw(s) as
I know the above is not true since there are plenty of non-zero elements in Schwartz class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps item 1 should be written to imply that $f$ is equal, almost everywhere, to some continuous function $g$ (i.e., in the "equivalence class" (mod equality a.e.) of $f$, there is at least one continuous function.)

Comment: Thanks I get that.